# Serve up an aspx page in an asp.net web app using Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (Katana)

Tags: asp.net, owin, katana

I have .net web application which includes a reference to OWIN.

This is all working fine and is serving up an web application using OWIN happily.

I want to include in the same web application an aspx web page. Is there a way I can inform my web application not to use OWIN for a single page (or a path).

Answer (score 0):

From investigation it looks like this might not be possible.

There are a couple of handler mappings which are at play.

System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory handles aspx pages
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler handles owin request

I can add them seperately and get close to what I require

i.e:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <clear />
    <add name="OWIN" path="test" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This will allow serve up owin stuff from a targetted path (test in mycase)

and

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <clear />
    <add name="APSX" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Will allow me serve up an aspx page - but only if the OWIN dlls are not in the bin directory.

If the OWIN dlls are present then the PageHandlerFactory will drop into OWIN handler and serve up via OWIN making. I.e. even though the OwinHttpHander is not specified, it still kicks into OWIN. I'm guessing this is built into the PageHandlerFactory code.

As far as I can tell, this means that *you can never have an aspx page in the same web application which uses Katana* (because it need the OWIN dlls, and then PageHandlerFactory calls into the OWIN code rather than aspx - deduced from testing rather than proved out right).